# Add functions to the queue for executing later. Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, progressive-web-apps

friends. 
I have stuck with a problem. 
I have this line of code

```js
var methodToQueue = {
  afterOffline: ƒ afterOffline(data)
  dependsOnNetworkStatus: true
  offline: ƒ offline(data)
  online: ƒ online()
}
```

It is an object and it will be dynamically changed if some redux action be execute offline. And I want to store it inside my redux store - 
`store.dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TO_ACTION_QUEUE', payload: methodToQueue.afterOffline });`

Reducer for it looks like this -

```js
const initialState = {
  functionsQueue: []
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
 case 'ADD_TO_ACTION_QUEUE':
   return Object.assign({}, state, {
  functionsQueue: state.functionsQueue.concat([action.payload])
   });
 default:
   return state;
 }
}
```

But it does not want to save methods to store it save `null`. Even if I am trying to use `JSON.stringify()` and store all object it saves only property without any logic.
`{ type: 'ADD_TO_ACTION_QUEUE', payload: JSON.stringify(methodToQueue) }` - will save only `dependsOnNetworkStatus: true`. 
Do you have any idea how to save some function to the redux store for after execution? It could be localStorage too. 
Thank you in advanced!

Comment: What is the action.payload value when you try to log it into the console before the return statement in your reducer ?

Comment: It looks like this  **console.log(methodToQueue.afterOffline)** `ƒ afterOffline(data) {
  console.log('after offline  logic goes here', data);
  var results = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__store__["a" /* default */].getState().testToSubmit;
  Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTE…`

Comment: How did "var results = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__store__["a" /* default */].getState().testToSubmit; Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTE…" get there ?

Comment: It happens because I imported this object from another file.

Comment: But you're not logging the action.payload inside the reducer but methodToQueue.afterOffline somewhere else.

Comment: When I am logging the action.payload inside the reducer it `null`, but when I am logging staff what I wanna put inside like payload it `ƒ afterOffline(data) { .....`

Comment: Please provide the content of the entire file where you import the afterOffline method and call the store.dispatch() function

Comment: I have done it inside **plunker** [https://plnkr.co/edit/eO3FSM?p=catalogue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux store is used to persist the **State**. A state can be a string, a number, an array of string and numbers and **not** functions' objects.

If you want to store functions, deal with its name since the **function name** is **a string**. Then, in another layer (middleware), catch that's name and call the related function by reflection.

Comment: Please don't do this.